# How can I fix my baked roughness being different from my unbaked roughness?

Tags: materials, texture-baking, roughness

I baked a roughness map. I baked the roughness on a 4096 by 4096 image, I also set the Color space on the image texture to non color.

I have my samples on 16 and tile size on 4096.
I deactivated noise threshold and denoise settings.

But my baked map has less detail, Is there something I'm doing wrong? Do I need to change some settings?

I'll attach pictures of the difference and my material

Using my normal roughness (1) vs Using the baked roughness map (2)

[image]

[image]

[image]

My blend file - https://we.tl/t-sab2ontJSX

P.s for those of you who will view my blend file. I'm trying to bake the gold material, It is called "Handle and guard"

I tried to bake the material from a plane for testing purposes, as you can see in the photos, but the actual mesh in my file is a sword

Comment: To have more detail, you need to use a higher resolution image for your bake, and/or you need your UVs to use more of the image space.  However, here, making a few reasonable assumptions, there's something else happening-- probably, you're not being careful about the color space of your bake, which should be non-color for roughness.

Comment: Alright Thanks!

Comment: How can I increase the size of the UVs? I'm using the smart UV project. Do I need to increase the island margin or do I need to scale it up with normally with "S"?

Comment: To increase the size of the UVs, yes, scale them up.  But for baking purposes, don't scale them outside the UV box, and don't create overlap.  For this question, you'd be best off providing a file from just before the bake (so with the bake settings you're intending to use, with the image resolution + type you're intending to use) and then rewording your question to something more general: "Why is my baked roughness map so different from the unbaked roughness?"

Comment: Alright thanks! I edited the question and added my blend file

Comment: Well, I was wrong-- it *is* about the resolution (I didn't notice the huge distortion on the noise texture.)  But you're already baking to 4k, and there isn't enough room for improvement on texture usage to make it work without going to 8k or even 16k, which is unrealistic.  If your goal is rendering elsewhere, I would recommend using a different technique for roughness that doesn't rely on such high frequency detail.  For example, it bakes fine when the noise's distortion is set to 100.

Comment: alright, Thanks a lot for your help Nathan!